# Modify text & html content on click <label> (Smarty language)

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

Working on that change, I found out some kind of solution provided by a user of the community, but it does not work at all.

JS

```
function changeText(productId){

var label = document.getElementById("additional_buy_" + productId);
var state = document.getElementById("anadir_" + productId);


    if (state.value === ""){
        state.value = "clicked";
        label.innerHTML = "Clicked";
    }
    else{
        state.value = "";
        label.innerHTML = "Click Me";
    }    

}
```

HTML

```
<input id="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" type="checkbox" class="additional_buy checkbox" name="additional_buy_" value="{$packcontent.id_product}" {if $packcontent.quantity <= 0 && !$packcontent.available_out_of_stock}disabled{/if}>
<label class="anadir_producto" for="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" onclick="changeText({$packcontent.id_product});" type="hidden"  id="anadir_{$packcontent.id_product}">Click me</label>
```

In the other hand I would like to change the span class inside the label, since the original one looks like this:

```
<label class="anadir_producto" for="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" onclick="changeText({$packcontent.id_product});" type="hidden"  id="anadir_{$packcontent.id_product}"><span class="icon-cart"></span>Click me</label>
```

Any clue why is it not working? I think that problem could come from the following code, since the function getElementById is jut trying to use a wrong ID, but I do not know how to apply the smarty function `additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}` on the JS code since this `id` is the one used for the label.

```
 var label = document.getElementById("some_addproductlabel_" + productId);
 var state = document.getElementById("some_product_state_" + productId);
```

******UPDATE******

After working around I found out another (maybe not that great) solution:

JS Code:

```
function changeText(element){
    element.innerHTML = "Clicked";   
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<input id="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" type="checkbox" class="additional_buy checkbox" name="additional_buy_" value="{$packcontent.id_product}" {if $packcontent.quantity <= 0 && !$packcontent.available_out_of_stock}disabled{/if}>
<label class="anadir_producto" for="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" onclick="changeText(this);" id="anadir"><span class="icon-ok"></span>Click me</label>
```

The problem comes when it does not toggles back to "Click me". Also is there any way to add a span in to the `element.innerHTML`? Since I would want to add a icon wich needs a span element.

Comment: Add a click event listener for that specific item.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Did the answer I provided help? If not let me know a little more about your project and I can maybe give you a more in depth answer.

Comment: Hey Joe, thank you for your time but I resolved it in the way of replacing HTML code.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
 var item = document.getElementsByClassName("class");

 item.addEventListener("click", function() {
     var param = this.getAttribute("param");
 });
```

I don't usually trust markup for code calls, but that's my opinion.

```
function changeText(element){
    if(element.innerHTML === "Clicked") {
        element.innerHTML = "Click Me";
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = "Clicked"
    }   
}
```

Best fix I can come up with for you since I really don't know what your trying to do with the labels, but this work if you would like to just toggle them. My advice, with a project like this, use jQuery. So much easier to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: But we still having the problem on adding the ElementID on the JS since it is added as smarty value

Comment: Then I would recommend going for the class then getting the needed attributes on click.

Comment: If that is the case then there is a javascript error we are not seeing. Have you checked your console or firebug? If you get the items by class you can define "this" as the item in place for "item." to gather the parameter values.

Comment: You can see this JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/Zb2QQ/1/ where it is not working with classes while this one http://jsfiddle.net/Zb2QQ is working. By the way, the console does not show any error

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the following code:

```
<input id="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" type="checkbox" class="additional_buy checkbox" name="additional_buy_" value="{$packcontent.id_product}" {if $packcontent.quantity <= 0 && !$packcontent.available_out_of_stock}disabled{/if}>
<label class="anadir_producto" for="additional_buy_{$packcontent.id_product}" onclick="changeText({$packcontent.id_product});" id="anadir"><span class="icon-ok" id="icon-ok_{$packcontent.id_product}"></span><span id="text_{$packcontent.id_product}">Click me</span></label>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(id){

    var element = document.getElementById('text_'+id);
    var icon = document.getElementById('icon-ok_'+id);
    if (element.innerHTML == 'Click me') {
        element.innerHTML = "Clicked";
        icon.innerHTML = '<img src="icon.png" />';
    }
    else {
        element.innerHTML = "Click me";
        icon.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
</script>
```

As you see I introduced 2 spans with ids to easier change text and set image. Of course when you use this code you need to put `icon.png` in the correct path (in my case into the main project folder) to display image properly. You can of course also put image here and hide it by default and when click only change it's style do display `block/inline` instead of loading image using `<img src`